# Mocking BLE controller, inferring destination characteristic problem

Tags: python, embedded, bluetooth-lowenergy, wireshark

I am trying to mock an Android-application based, BLE controller of some device (a Tennis Launcher).

In order to do that, I sniffed the packets transferred within the connection, and loaded them into Wireshark so I could extract the sent data, and the destination characterestics of the device.
[image: Sent packets info from wireshark]

I'm using Python's Bleak library to connect with the device, using it, I listed all device's available characteristics:

```
  Characteristic: Vendor specific (Properties: ['write-without-response'])(uuid: ****) (Handle: 15) 
  Characteristic: Vendor specific (Properties: ['notify'])(uuid: ****) (Handle: 18) 
  Characteristic: Vendor specific (Properties: ['notify'])(uuid: ****) (Handle: 18) 
  Characteristic: Vendor specific (Properties: ['read', 'write'])(uuid: ****) (Handle: 25) 
  Characteristic: Vendor specific (Properties: ['read', 'write'])(uuid: ****) (Handle: 28) 
  Characteristic: Vendor specific (Properties: ['read', 'write'])(uuid: ****) (Handle: 31) 
  Characteristic: Vendor specific (Properties: ['read', 'write'])(uuid: ****) (Handle: 34) 
  Characteristic: Vendor specific (Properties: ['read', 'write'])(uuid: ****) (Handle: 37) 
  Characteristic: Vendor specific (Properties: ['read', 'write'])(uuid: ****) (Handle: 40) 
  Characteristic: Vendor specific (Properties: ['read', 'write'])(uuid: ****) (Handle: 43) 
  Characteristic: Vendor specific (Properties: ['read', 'write'])(uuid: ****) (Handle: 46) 
  Characteristic: Vendor specific (Properties: ['write'])(uuid: ****) (Handle: 49) 
  Characteristic: Vendor specific (Properties: ['write'])(uuid: ****) (Handle: 52) 
  Characteristic: Unknown (Properties: ['read'])(uuid: ****) (Handle: 56) 
  Characteristic: Unknown (Properties: ['write'])(uuid: ****) (Handle: 58) 
  Characteristic: Unknown (Properties: ['indicate'])(uuid: ****) (Handle: 60) 
  Characteristic: Unknown (Properties: ['write-without-response'])(uuid: ****) (Handle: 63) 
  Characteristic: Unknown (Properties: ['notify'])(uuid: ****)(Handle: 65) 
  Characteristic: Unknown (Properties: ['write-without-response'])(uuid: ****) (Handle: 68) 
  Characteristic: Manufacturer Name String (Properties: ['read'])(uuid: ****) (Handle: 71) 
  Characteristic: Model Number String (Properties: ['read'])(uuid: ****) (Handle: 73) 
  Characteristic: Serial Number String (Properties: ['read'])(uuid: ****) (Handle: 75) 
  Characteristic: Hardware Revision String (Properties: ['read'])(uuid: ****) (Handle: 77) 
  Characteristic: Firmware Revision String (Properties: ['read'])(uuid: ****) (Handle: 79) 
  Characteristic: Software Revision String (Properties: ['read'])(uuid: ****) (Handle: 81) 
  Characteristic: System ID (Properties: ['read'])(uuid: ****) (Handle: 83) 
  Characteristic: IEEE 11073-20601 Regulatory Cert. Data List (Properties: ['read'])(uuid: ****) (Handle: 85) 
  Characteristic: PnP ID (Properties: ['read'])(uuid: ****) (Handle: 87) 
  Characteristic: Vendor specific (Properties: ['write-without-response'])(uuid: ****) (Handle: 90) 
  Characteristic: Vendor specific (Properties: ['read'])(uuid: ****) (Handle: 92) 
  Characteristic: Vendor specific (Properties: ['read'])(uuid: ****) (Handle: 94) 
  Characteristic: Vendor specific (Properties: ['read'])(uuid: ****) (Handle: 96) 
  Characteristic: Vendor specific (Properties: ['read'])(uuid: ****) (Handle: 98) 
  Characteristic: Vendor specific (Properties: ['write-without-response'])(uuid: ****) (Handle: 100) 
  Characteristic: Vendor specific (Properties: ['read'])(uuid: ****) (Handle: 102) 
  Characteristic: Vendor specific (Properties: ['write'])(uuid: ****) (Handle: 104) 
  Characteristic: Vendor specific (Properties: ['read'])(uuid: ****) (Handle: 106)
```

Noticing, that the destination Hanldes that were captured (0x14 aka decimal 20, and 0x10 aka decimal 16) are missing.

Perhaps there are service handle or descriptor handles which feature these handle numbers (Can share them on demand), although I'm looking to write to a characteristic, therefore I'm quite lost.

I tried writing to any of the characteristics, but that obviously wouldn't succeed (aka result with the relevant response).

Comment: What's your question? Are you asking where the missing handles are? Or are yoou asking why writing to the characteristics is failing?

Comment: How can I access or send packets to the missing handles?